# When will awk treat newline character as `;` and when not?

Tags: awk

I'm reading the famous awk tutorial from http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html.

In which it mentioned `To be precise, in the original AWK you can insert a new line character after the curly braces, and at the end of a command, but not elsewhere.`

I got the following multiple line awk command test on my mac and remote host, with `awk` and `gawk`:

```
  awk '$0 !~ /special_signal/  \
       { my_dict[$1] += $2 }
       END { for (uid in my_dict)   \
             if (my_dict[uid] > 1)  \
             print uid, my_dict[uid]}' raw_data | sort -nk2
```

The original one-line awk command of the above awk code is:

```
awk '$0 !~ /special_signal/ { my_dict[$1] += $2 } END { for (uid in my_dict) if (my_dict[uid] > 1) print uid, my_dict[uid]}' raw_data | sort -nk2
```

Through my experiments. I found on both `awk` and `gawk`, the first `\` is essential, without it, the code will behave differently compare to the original one-liner. The effect of new-line character is identical to `;`

But the second and third `\` after `for (uid in my_dict)` and `if (my_dict[uid] > 1)` in all these two awk edition are unnecessary.

I removed them, the multiple code act as exactly the same as one-liner.

Then I replaced the second and third `\` with `;`, which will leads the multiple-line code produce a wrong result.

This further proved that If I add a new-line character after  after `for (uid in my_dict)` and `if (my_dict[uid] > 1)`, they'll just connect these two code blocks with the code of next-line,  act like a `\`.

My conclusion seems conflict with the tutorial.

So, indeed,  at which circumstances will awk treat new-line as `;` and at which as treat it as `\`?

---

PS: for the sake of test, I've made some test content for `raw_data`:

```
Tom 2
Tom 5
Jack 3
Mary 5
special_signal 5
Tim 10
Don 22
Jan 3
Jack 8
special_signal 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between your example lines is: Can the command be finished at that point? A pattern can stand alone; in that case `{print}` is assumed. The next line is considered a second command (not the second part of the first one); the pattern is assumed to be always true.

But within a control structure (`for`, `if`) you cannot finish the command at that point thus it is clear that the command is continued on the next line.

It is similar in shell code:

```
echo foo &&
echo bar
```

is interpreted differently than

```
echo foo
&& echo bar
```

so you need

```
echo foo \
&& echo bar
```

With the difference to `awk` that only one way works. But there may be similar cases.

Comment: This `can it be finished?` comes from the view of human being. But for awk, `{ for (uid in my_dict) if (my_dict[uid] > 1) print uid, my_dict[uid]}` and `{ for (uid in my_dict); if (my_dict[uid] > 1); print uid, my_dict[uid]}` are all executable command and act differently. So, by what logic the awk designer judged the `can it be finished?`, do you know the mechanism of that?

Comment: @Zen No, the "can it be finished?" refers to the `awk` perspective i.e. the `awk` syntax, of course.

Comment: I'm confused. Because I test it, and a single `for (uid in my_dict)` can run. Though nothing print out, it simply iterate over the `my_dict`, and do nothing. And a single `if (my_dict[uid] > 1)` simply checks if there is a my_uid, if uid in my_dict, and if my_dict[uid] > 1, then do nothing.

Comment: I mean, did the author write something like: if we got a bare `for block` or `if block` we treat new-line as `\`. How could I figure it out by reading like source code or something as a newbee who has no C-language knowledge.

Comment: For practice consideration I can accept this answer, until I met another exception next time. But I really want to know if there is an official doc or something.

Comment: @Zen In my GNU Awk 4.1.1 `{for (uid in my_dict);}` works but `{for (uid in my_dict)}` doesn't. I wasn't aware of this being legal; doesn't make sense to me.